# How to increase the vertical distance between proof lines in a prooftrees environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, draw, prooftrees

With the following code I tried to create a proof tree with the prooftrees environment wich is based on the forest package which is based on the pgf/TikZ package:

```
\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{ot-tableau}
%\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand*{\lif}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\rightarrow}}}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\begin{tableau}
    {
        line no sep = 1.5cm,
        just sep = 1.5cm, % Set separation of justification
        for tree = { s sep'=10mm},
%         close with = \absurd
    }
    [\sim A \supset B, just={P1}
    [\sim A, just={P2}
    [\sim B, draw, circle, just={$\sim$K}
    [\neg(Q \lif R), just={From (2)}
    [Q, just={From (4)}
    [\neg R, s sep=30mm, just={From (4)} %Note "s sep" to
    %spread fork below
    [\neg(P \land Q), just={Alternatives from (1)}
    [\neg P, close, just={Alternatives from (7)}
    ]
    [\neg Q, close
    ]
    ]
    [R, close]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
    ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

Now my problem is, that I tried to encircle an elementary wff (code line 21) but the drawn circle is overlapping with the proof lines before and after as you can see in the output:

[image]

The solution I would like to find would be to increase the vertical distances between the proof lines. The only problem is that I don't know how best to do it.

Perhaps there are other ways to deal with the whole problem of overlapping. This solutions would be welcome too.

Many thanks for any help

Nitzgi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `rounded corners` instead of `circle`.

Comment: Thank you very much! But that would only be a half-satisfactory solution, insofar as I definitely want to use a real circle.

Answer (score 3):

This is a crude version which avoids the worst outcome. I think a better solution is really needed in `prooftrees`. However, as I don't know how difficult that will be or when it might happen, perhaps this will be useful to somebody in the meantime.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[tableaux]{prooftrees}
\newcommand*{\lif}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\rightarrow}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tableau}
    {
        line no sep = 1.5cm,
        just sep = 1.5cm, % Set separation of justification
        for tree = { s sep'=10mm},
%         close with = \absurd
%         before drawing tree={for tree={if grouped={red,typeset node}{blue,typeset node}}},
%         proof tree dadfygio,
    }
    [\sim A \supset B, just={P1}
      [\sim A, just={P2}
        [\sim B, draw, circle, just={$\sim$K}, before typesetting nodes={not grouped, no edge}, outer sep=-5mm
          [\neg(Q \lif R), just={From (2)}, before typesetting nodes={not grouped, no edge}
            [Q, just={From (4)}
              [\neg R, s sep=30mm, just={From (4)} %Note "s sep" to
              %spread fork below
                [\neg(P \land Q), just={Alternatives from (1)}
                  [\neg P, close, just={Alternatives from (7)}
                  ]
                  [\neg Q, close
                  ]
                ]
                [R, close]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{tableau}
\end{document}
```

This won't give quite the output below because the current version on CTAN causes that misplaced closure symbol which I somehow missed before. I've just fixed that in the code so, if I can't come up with a good solution to the enlargement issue soon, I'll upload an interim update to fix the closure symbol, at least.

[image: rough correction for enlarged node with upcoming fix for stray closures]

Comment: I don't know if this would look better if the distance between lines was increased for all of them. I'd also be tempted to reduce `inner sep` for the `circle` node to reduce the space required. On the whole, I'd prefer highlighting the wff some other way (e.g. bold, box, different colour or whatever). I have no idea what I meant about a better solution in `prooftrees` as I can't now think what that would look like.

Comment: I also just noticed this proof appears to switch negation symbols and sentence letters half way through!